# CRM How to Find Account without Active Contacts

Tags: sql, reporting-services, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

This should be pretty straightforward however I'm stump. Basically find all Accounts that don't have Active contacts. SO all Accounts which contacts are all inactive, or Accounts that don't have any contacts.

I tried two ways, one query with left join and one with query with 'Not Exists' but keeps returning nothing:

Query 1:

```
SELECT a.name, a.statecode AS AccountStatus, c.StateCode AS ContactStatus, c.FullName
FROM dbo.Account a
LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c 
ON a.AccountId = c.ParentCustomerId
AND c.statecode = 0 --active contacts
WHERE c.ContactId IS NULL
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT *
  FROM dbo.Account a
WHERE accountid IN (Select accountid FROM Account)
   AND NOT EXISTS 
(Select c.ParentCustomerId FROM dbo.Contact c 
WHERE c.StateCode = 0 
AND c.ParentCustomerId IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: may be you have 0 records like that :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement translates to:

- All accounts
- For which no contact exists that is active

Would translate to

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  dbo.Account a -- all accounts
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS( -- for which no contact exists
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      dbo.Contact c
    WHERE
      c.ParentCustomerId=a.AccountId AND
      c.StateCode<>0 -- that is active
  );
```

Comment: Thanks yeah this is the same number of rows returned when I use the left join actually but thanks much for confirming

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT ac.accountid,ac.name
FROM account ac
LEFT JOIN contact ca
ON ac.accountid=ca.parentcustomerid
GROUP BY ac.accountid,ac.name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ca.contactid)=0 
OR SUM(CASE WHEN ca.statecode=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)>0
```